# Two table primary reference to one primary key on another table

Tags: mysql

Im here with a little problem with my inventory and I've been pondering with idea of this little schema here.
Is it possible or is there another way I can achieve this kind of schema below?
[image]

I can cheat my way through this problem by just having my application identify what `itemID` should be inserted into the `tbl_stocks` but I fear when the `ID` of either medicine or bandage is updated, that would leave an issue in my `tbl_stocks`.
Any suggestions on how to achieve my target?

Comment: Can you modify the Table `tbl_Stocks`?

Comment: Yes, I am allowed to edit them incase there are some items that are needed to be pulled out or when there is a mistake in the restocking process. the `tbl_stocks` is used to distribute items to other buildings inside a table called `tbl_inventory`. the referencing of `Building_ID` in the `tbl_stocks` was a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you have 2 entries in such a table that can became different shapes.

So add a reference for both tables to `tbl_Stocks` one column `Medicine_ID VARCHAR(10) NULL` and a `Bandage_ID VARCHAR(10) NULL`
So of curse you have a null column in this table for every entry, but later you can easy join this table.

If more and more tables come as expected you need a crosstable for each "Shape" .. One `Medicine_ID x tbl_Stocks` and one `Bandage_ID x tbl_Stocks`. This is fast and a good design, but also brings more maintenance effort.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. I was thinking of doing the same thing. I was hoping for a different answer but looks like this really is the answer.